# Trouble connecting to wireless via Clear Hub Express

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have never had trouble connecting to wireless signals before.

I just moved into a new apartment and got a [Clear Hub Express](http://www.clear.com/support/download/modems/clear-hub-express). It hooked up fine and my wife, who uses Mac, has connected to the internet with not trouble.

While my computer connects to the signal, it will not load any web pages. When I connect to the router via an ethernet cable, I can access the web with no problem.

Clear's tech support says they can't do anything from their end, and suggested I talk to Ubuntu's support (this is where you all come in). Has anyone figured out how to connect to a Clear Hub Express wireless signal via Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact problem. If you look at ifconfig you will notice you don't have a dns server. I can get it to work by plugging it in hard wired then it will retain the dns servers ip. You can then unplug and the wireless will work. I'm going to check the firmware on the modem but its at work and I'm at home. The problem is with the modem and not your device. I've used two of these modems and same results with both.